# Get list of values from column based on dictionary with list of indices

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>      price    code
1695     765       0
1700     854       1
1702     975       0
1703     452       0
1704     275       0
...
2169     754      14
2174     743      14
2181     932      15
```

I want to create dictionary with the codes as keys and the prices as the values.
I have tried to do it this way:

```
groups=df.groupby('code').groups
groups
>>>{0:[1695,1702,1703,1704], 1:[1700,...]...,14:[2169,2174],15:[2181]}
```

I have tried to define the price column in the groupby  but this added the proces to the key and not to the list of values, so it would be like {(0,765):[1695],(0,975):[1702]...}.

I haven't seen much information regard the groups method in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html) .

**My desired iutput will look like:**

```
{0 : [ 765,975,452,275],1:[854],...,14:[754,743],15:[932]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `list`s and then convert to `dict`:

```
d = df.groupby('code')['price'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Or use dict comprehension:

```
d = {k: list(v['price']) for k, v in df.groupby('code')}
#similar alternative
d = {k: list(v) for k, v in df.groupby('code')['price']}
```

---

```
print (d)
0: [765, 975, 452, 275], 1: [854], 14: [754, 743], 15: [932]}
```